# How do I make fields in DTO optional using lombok?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

So I have a DTO like this,

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class PersonDTO {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private String phone;
  private String other;
}
```

I am passing the following payload to an external API

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "phone": "123",
    "address": "abc"
}
```

This is throwing me 500 internal error:

```
HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404: "{<EOL> "status": "Error", <EOL> "message": "Error validating JSON. Error: - Invalid type Null, expected String."}"
```

If I comment out `other` property in DTO then I will successfully get 200 response. I thought `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation is supposed to ignore the properties that are not present but it seems that's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that they can't parse `Null` into `String`. That's very interesting error and fooled me first.
Your json object with other field `null` probably looks like this:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "phone": "123",
    "address": "abc"
}
```

So somehow this API can't just wrap quotes around `null` and tells you it's not able to parse this.

Therefore I guess you need to set the value of `other` to an empty string:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class PersonDTO {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private String phone;
  private String other = ""; //empty because external api can't handle null
}
```

Comment: I see now. I used this annotation `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to solve the issue and it worked. Do you think this should be the right approach though?

Comment: Wow I was about to write an answert where I tell you that this annotation could help but I thought it would only create exactly the payload you added. Therefore I told you this because yeah the above reasons. Well then I guess I missunderstood something.  And it' s completly fine to use this annotation for this. Maybe check again if you still need e.g. `JsonIgnoreProperties`

Comment: Awesome! Appreciate the explanation :D

Comment: I'm actually still very confused what's happening but I'm happy that I somehow could help you with that! :D

Answer (score 3):

you are using lombok's `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`.  So you have to use one or the other. If you don't want an all args constructor you'll have to implement your own.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class PersonDTO {
  private String name;
  private String address;
  private String phone;
  private String other;

  public PersonDTO(String name, String address, String phone) {
    super(name, address, phone, "");
  }

  public PersonDTO(String name, String address, String phone, String other) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.other = other
  }

}
```

Or if you have control over AND this is a spring boot app, you could try using `required=false` in your controller so you can continue to use an all arg constructor.

```
public PersonDTO getPerson(
      @PathVariable(value = "name") String name,
      @PathVariable(value = "address") String address
      @PathVariable(value = "phone") String phone
      @PathVariable(value = "other", required = false) String other) { 

 ....

}
```

Comment: It's an external api he doesn't have the control.

Comment: i saw that. but it's seems odd that he has access to the DTO but not the API.

Comment: DTO is Data Transfer Object. Doesn't need to be on the server side.  But I got consfused 3 times by this question... Caused 3 answers :/

Comment: i'm up on DTOS ;)  the post is tagged with spring-boot and says  "passing" ..  "external API".   the question probably could be worded to be a bit more clear :)

Comment: Yeah alright. As I said I got confused too. But he solved his problem and it's working :D That's good! Have a nice one bud ;)

Answer (score 1):

If attributes are nullable then you can use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`. This will allow to set null value in the attributes. I guess, by default it doesn't allow null value.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` is the solution as you said in the comment. This annotation tells the serializer to ignore fields that are null. If you don't add this the payload will look like this:

```json
{
    "name": "John",
    "phone": "123",
    "address": "abc",
    "other": null
}
```